# How do you use Linkify to issue a startActivity instead of doing a browser link

Tags: android

How do you use Linkify to cause clicking the link to issue a startActivity instead of doing a bowser link? All the examples I've seen use linkify to link to a URL: I want to have clicking the link to cause a transer to an Activity via startActivity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you already have the link part working, that is your `<intent-filter>` and **scheme** to start the Activity.

Then what you need is to use [Linkify.addLinks(TextView text, Pattern p, String scheme, Linkify.MatchFilter matchFilter, Linkify.TransformFilter transformFilter)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/util/Linkify.html#addLinks%28android.widget.TextView,%20java.util.regex.Pattern,%20java.lang.String,%20android.text.util.Linkify.MatchFilter,%20android.text.util.Linkify.TransformFilter%29) to specify the **scheme** you selected in the previous step, let's say `"com.example.myscheme"`.

Comment: That was the connection I needed. I'll have the link forward to a URL that is being intercepted via an intent-filter. Thanks much!